# Visualizar Eventos de una base de datos en FullCalendar

Tags: sql, json, asp.net-core

Estoy realizando un fullcalendar en Asp net Core y enlazo a una BD en SQL,el problema es que al momento de llenar mi fullcalendar con los eventos no los muestra, si tengo respuesta de mi Json pero no se plasman en mi calendario, adjunto mi código :

```
 function displayTasks() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            events: function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/TraeCitas",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                   success: function (result) {

                       [
                       title= result[0].titulo,
                       start= result[0].fecha
                       ]



                  },
                    error: function (err) {

                        alert('No funciona!!!');
                    }

                });

            },


            locale: 'es',
            weekends: true,//visualiza fines de semana SABADO, DOMINGO.
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',//Botones para avanzar, retroceder, y para ver el día actual.
                center: 'title',//visualiza el nombre del mes y año.
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'//visualiza botones del mes, por semana o por día.
            },
            displayEventTime: false,
            // open up the display form when a user clicks on an event
            //Este método es cuando se da click en un evento y se muestra al //usuario:



            editable: true,
            timezone: "UTC",
            droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
            selectable: true,








            dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
                prevTime = typeof currentTime === 'undefined' || currentTime === null
                    ? new Date().getTime() - 1000000
                   : currentTime;
                currentTime = new Date().getTime();

                if (currentTime - prevTime < 500) {
                    //double click call back
                   // alert("this is double click");
                   $('#createEventModal').modal('show');
               }
            }



        });


    }
```

Comment: supongo que title y star son variables que declaras previamente verdad? tambien te recomiendo que borres el codigo que está comentado, ya que es irrelevante y hace un poco más dificl de entender el código

Comment: Ok gracias por la retro, sobre las variables si las declare en la función de events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas retornar el valor al final de tu llamada ajax con un `callback`, para esto debes pasar tus valores como un array( el array lo llamé `eventos`):

```
 function displayTasks() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/TraeCitas",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                   success: function (result) {
                       var eventos = [];
                       eventos.push({
                         title: result[0].titulo,
                         start: result[0].fecha
                       });
                       callback(eventos);
                  },
                    error: function (err) {
                        alert('No funciona!!!');
                    }
                });
            },
            locale: 'es',
            weekends: true,//visualiza fines de semana SABADO, DOMINGO.
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',//Botones para avanzar, retroceder, y para ver el día actual.
                center: 'title',//visualiza el nombre del mes y año.
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'//visualiza botones del mes, por semana o por día.
            },
            displayEventTime: false,
            // open up the display form when a user clicks on an event
            //Este método es cuando se da click en un evento y se muestra al //usuario:

            editable: true,
            timezone: "UTC",
            droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
            selectable: true,
            //Se activa cuando se arrastra un evento a otro lugar

            dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
                prevTime = typeof currentTime === 'undefined' || currentTime === null
                    ? new Date().getTime() - 1000000
                   : currentTime;
                currentTime = new Date().getTime();

                if (currentTime - prevTime < 500) {
                   $('#createEventModal').modal('show');
               }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Que tal, gracias por tu ayuda, en la función callback(eventos); si tengo datos pero al terminar no me detecta ningún dato dando el siguiente error:     Uncaught ReferenceError: callback is not defined, le puse los datos para ver si respondía pero aún así al llegar al callback, aparece nuevamente el error.

Comment: disculpa, estuve ausente todo el fin de semana, pudiste resolver el problema?

Comment: Que tal, si lo resolví declarando callback(), dentro de la función, deje el código final abajo, gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: es cierto, no noté que no los puse en los parametros de la función porque creí que ya estaban, saludos

Answer (score 1):

Listo, dejo mi resultado final, las citas las muestra sin problemas, gracias por sus tips y ayuda, complete la función dejo el link consultado y código final.
[link consultado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437575/jquery-fullcalendar-callback-is-not-defined-error?newreg=ac2a6fc976ea4852b715f15a12068cbd)

```
   function displayTasks() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/TraeCitas",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                   success: function (result) {
                       var events = [];
                       for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

                           events.push({

                               title: result[i].titulo,
                               start: result[i].fecha                      

                           })
                       }
                       callback(events);                      
                    },

                    error: function (err) {

                        alert('No funciona!!!');
                    }                    
                });

            },
```